# Align Label To Middle Off Drop Down Selector Box - Woocommerce

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Thank you for taking the time to read this. I have tried everything to get the "size label" on my woocommerce product page, https://www.teamkodered.com/shop/adidas-speed-50-boxing-gloves, to line up with the drop down selector box to its right,  as the colour label correctly does. See screenshot for clear illustration.

I put in CSS code that worked for the colour label, but just can't get the size label to align the same. Am at my wits end! :) The custom code I added and in place is below.

```
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations td, .woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations th {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: #ccd0d1;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

td, th {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}

td.value {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not aligned middle because of the `clear` button beside the `select` option that's why that element creating extra height.

> You can do this in two way one is CSS and the Second is JavaScript
>
> By CSS you can give this CSS `position: absolute;` to the clear button

**CSS**

```
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .reset_variations{position: absolute;}
.single_variation_wrap{margin-top: 25px;display: inline-block;}
```

> By javascript, you can remove that element from beside select and
> append new `tr` inside `table` and move an element in that `td`. Try
> the below code. code will go active theme function.php file.

**JavaScript**

```
function add_custom_js(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var reset_variations = jQuery('.variations').find('.reset_variations')[0].outerHTML;
        jQuery('.variations').find('.reset_variations').remove();
        jQuery('.variations tbody').append('<tr><td class="label"></td><td class="value">'+reset_variations+'</td></tr>');
        jQuery('.variations select').on('change',function(){
            var show = false;
            jQuery('.variations select').each(function(){
                if( jQuery(this).val() != '' ){
                    show = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if( show ){
                jQuery('.reset_variations').css( 'visibility', 'visible' ).hide().fadeIn();
            }else{
                jQuery('.reset_variations').css( 'visibility', 'hidden' );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php 
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_custom_js', 10, 1 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the Javascript and stripped out the CSS i put in place. Thank you so much. You are a god send!

Can I please ask you one other question: The product page on mobile puts the product title up against the images, instead of underneath if there are not enough images to stack it? I have inspected the code but i cant find any sort of inline code, or overflow code.  https://www.teamkodered.com/shop/adidas-aiba-style-training-head-guard/

I believe this is the culprit <h1=class "product_title entry-title"> but cant get it right on mobile.

Upvoted of course! :)

Comment: Welcome... can you ask other questions as a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: I will do, thanks so much again. Respect to you.